# NPM error but no packages to restore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package

I'm getting the [attached error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GawdU.jpg) when attempting to publish my app.

Error text: This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.

When I attempt a restore, I get a message that there are no packages that need restoring. Following the advice of other StackOverflow posts, I deleted the packages folder and ran the Restore command again. Same result. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Would you add the error to the question body as text? If the image is no longer available in the future a big piece of information will be missing from this question. Also, images are not good for SEO.

Comment: Is NPM related to the question? Looks like your issues are with NuGet and not NPM. What restore command are you using?

Comment: I attempted using the "restore NuGet packages" option, then tried "Update-Package -reinstall" command

Comment: If you check your packages folder, is the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2` folder there?

Comment: @Clint No, but Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.8.2 is. And that version is also what's listed in packages.config

Comment: Can you open your csproj with a text editor and see if it's referencing 1.3.2? If it is try changing it to 2.8.2

Comment: @Clint I was able to fix this with the following: deleted the packages folder both in the project and in the root (Visual Studio 2017) folder. Then manually re-added the offending package (it still didn't update when attempting to restore). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it's been resolved. You should add your comment as an answer and accept it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this with the following: deleted the packages folder both in the project and in the root (Visual Studio 2017) folder. Then manually re-added the offending package (it still didn't update when attempting to restore). Thanks for your help!